# Opening and Saving non Excel files with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have files that when opened, are opened in Excel, but they are not Excel files themselves (they just convert when opened). I want to be able to pull some of the information in these files into another Excel sheet, but since they are not Excel files, I cant just link the files.

I want to open these files with VBA (they will open as an Excel file) and then save them as permanent excle files so I can use them as I want.

To open the file, I have this code:

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, _
ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Function OpenAnyFile(FileToOpen As String)

Call ShellExecute(0, "Open", FileToOpen & vbNullString, _
vbNullString, vbNullString, 1)

End Function

Sub OpenFile()

Call OpenAnyFile("C:\Filename")

End Sub
```

But I am unsure how to save the now opened file in this code.

Comment: What happens if you use `Workbooks.Open` or `Workbooks.OpenText` instead of using API calls?

Comment: @Rory It opens the file in excel, but its not formatting correctly. There is some special process/conversion that happens when you open the file and then it converts to a proper excel file.

Comment: Then you probably need to specify some of the parameters. What format is the file?

Comment: @Rory They are .TDMS files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're placing this code into and running it from the Excel VBE, then you should just be able to use the the `SaveAs` Method (documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx)) for `Workbook` like so

```
Dim owb As Workbook

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

fname = "Filename goes here (include .extension)"
fpath = "Path goes here"

Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath & "\" & fname)

With owb
    .SaveAs fpath & "\" & fname & ".xlsx", 51
    .Close
End With
```

> SaveAs Parameters as per MSDN Documentation
>
> expression **.SaveAs(FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local)***

Comment: How does it know that i would like to save the newly opened excel file, and not the excel file that the Macro is running in?

Comment: Thanks. This would work however I cant use Workbooks.Open (for whatever reason the formatting doesnt carry over)